# How to add move function to multiple items with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a move function to multiple items on a page with Javascript - a simple increase in the Y axis. I'm new to Javascript and have been getting an error message for the following code, is it something I am missing?

for the script:

```
const eyes = document.querySelectorAll('.character');

function move(){
    this.classList.toggle('move');
}

eyes.forEach(eyes => character.addEventListener('click', move));
```

I'm am getting the following error message:

`uncaught ReferenceError: character is not defined at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)`

Comment: You have a typo in the forEach line, `eyes => character.add` should be `eye => eye.add`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables.  The code you're using for your `forEach` function declares a locally scoped `eyes` for use inside your function, not `character`.

```
eyes.forEach(eyes => character.addEventListener('click', move));
```

in your code above, character is not declared and doesn't exist.

Try something like this:

```js
const eyes = document.querySelectorAll('.eyes');

function move(){
    this.classList.toggle('move');

}

eyes.forEach(eye => eye.addEventListener('click', move));
```

```css
.character {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


.eyes {
display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.move {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="world">
<div class="character"><div class="eyes"></div><div class="eyes"></div></div>
<div class="character"><div class="eyes"></div><div class="eyes"></div></div>
<div class="character"><div class="eyes"></div><div class="eyes"></div></div>
</div>
```